# Use unset result without defining a new array in php

Tags: php, arrays, implode, on-the-fly

I am trying to create a dynamic link, in this way:

- Take an array
- Search for the key of one element
- Delete this element
- Implode the array elements to a string
- Show the string as a parameter in the link

I am doing it like it follows:

```
 $url_langs=array('fra','cat','hun'...); //CURRENT LANGS in use

 $all_langs=array('eng','fra','por','ser','cat','dan','hun','fin','est','esl',...);

 foreach($all_langs as $lang){
    echo (in_array($lang,$url_langs))?'<a href="' . implode('|',unset($url_langs[array_search($lang,$url_langs)])) . '">' . $lang . '</b> ':'<a href="' . implode('|',$url_langs) . '|' . $lang . '">' . $lang . '</a> ';
 }
```

Well, as you can see. I iterate the array which contains all the available languages, and check if it is already in use or not. If it is in use, I show a link to not use it; and the same for the contrary case.

As the [php manual (unset)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) says: *"No value is returned."*. So I can't use unset on the fly. My questions are:

1. Is there any **alternative form** to achieve it?
2. I could use the long `if` sentence, and define a new array which I will then use for the implode() function. But, isn't it strange? Crate a new array if my goal is make it as plain text?
3. I could use a str_replace to remove this part of the string once imploded... but this I can't do it on the fly, neither.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_diff(a1, a2) will return an array of a1 values which are not in a2.
So converting $lang to an array value as array($lang) and taking array difference will give you the desired values

You are also missing an `</a>` at the first `<a href=`

```
$url_langs=array('fra','cat','hun'...); //CURRENT LANGS in use
$all_langs=array('eng','fra','por','ser','cat','dan','hun','fin','est','esl',...);
foreach($all_langs as $lang){
    echo (in_array($lang,$url_langs)) ? 
          '<a href="' 
         . implode('|',array_diff($url_langs, array($lang))) 
         . '">' . $lang . '</a></b> '     :
          '<a href="' 
         . implode('|',$url_langs) . '|' . $lang . '">' . $lang . '</a> ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a great answer. There was a missing close bracket in your first implode (just for further references) ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for that, I corrected it. And you are wellcome, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/array_diff%20array_diff) in your case:

```
$new_langs = array_diff($all_langs, $url_langs);
print_r($new_langs);
// this will print
// Array([0] => eng [2] => por [3] => ser [5] => dan [7] => fin [8] => est [9] => esl)
```